# When I change GroupBox style, GroupBox header property becomes hidden?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to change `GroupBox` style but when I do this I can't show `GroupBox` header and `Groupbox` header becomes hidden.
I want a GroupBox exactly like following image:

https://pasteboard.co/JLWHAHL.jpg

With the following properties:

> CornerRadius="9" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" Header
> location=at top on the GroupBox border

I tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
 <GroupBox x:Name="Search_GroupBox" Header="Search"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="295,64,0,0" Width="277" Height="70">
    <GroupBox.Style>
        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                        <Border CornerRadius="9" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Canvas.ZIndex="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="70" Margin="-2,0,-3,-1" Height="20">
                            <TextBlock Text="Search" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="DemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </GroupBox.Style>
 </GroupBox>
```

Comment: Please note that the Image link is no longer valid, try to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include [`ContentPresenter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter?view=net-5.0) element in the style in order to show both the `Header` content and the `GroupBox` content itself.

So, your style should be more like this:

```xml
<GroupBox x:Name="Search_GroupBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="295,64,0,0" Width="277" Height="70">
    <GroupBox.Style>
        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border x:Name="Header" Padding="3,1,3,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border CornerRadius="9" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="1">
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Canvas.ZIndex="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="70" Margin="-2,0,-3,-1" Height="20">
                            <TextBlock Text="Search" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="DemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </GroupBox.Style>
</GroupBox>
```

However, as a better approach, it's recommended to edit a copy of the original style of the `GroupBox` control leaving `ContentPresenter`s each in place.

#### Update

A style similar to the one in the [image](https://pasteboard.co/JLWHAHL.jpg) you attached would require a simple edit in the default `Template` of the `GroupBox` control.

The tricky thing about it is the `CornerRadius` property, that's why we are going to override the default style and edit it:

```xml
<GroupBox Header="Search" Height="70">
    <GroupBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            
                            <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" 
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" 
                                    CornerRadius="11" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                            
                            <Border BorderBrush="White" 
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
                                    CornerRadius="11" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                                <Border.OpacityMask>
                                    <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="10">
                                        <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                            <BorderGapMaskConverter/>
                                        </MultiBinding.Converter>
                                        <Binding ElementName="Header" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Border.OpacityMask>
                                
                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="10">
                                    <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="9"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                            
                            <Border x:Name="Header" Grid.Column="1" Padding="3,1,3,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"
                                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                            
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </GroupBox.Style>
    
    <!-- Place your content here... -->
    
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: Please see the link of the GroupBox image above.

Comment: @reza_jafery Which border you want to have a `CornerRadius` of 9, the header or the `GroupBox` content?

Comment: GroupBox Content CornerRadius=9 and GroupBox Header=without border

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but when I put the StackPanel, the GroupBox itself completely Becomes hidden.

Comment: @reza_jafery I've updated my answer check it out.

Comment: @reza_jafery By the way, I've changed the `StackPanel` with a `Grid` in the first code sample to fix the problem you noted, but the first code sample is not the style you want, try the second code sample instead.

Comment: Updated part is my exact answer that i wanted , I found the answer with your help ,thanks ahmed